# Rails 3.1 app running with SSL - TLS server name indication support error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger, osx-server

I have a simple Rails 3.1.rc6 app that I'm using to try to test SSL configurations on my test server (OS X 10.7 Server). I'm using Phusion Passenger and Apache.

I can run the app with no problem when not using SSL. When I enable SSL, either via Apache or via `config.force_ssl = true` in my `environments/production.rb` file, a page loads without an error, but it's mostly empty and it's not my site. It appears as if it's trying to serve files out of an empty directory.

I checked the [Edge Rails Documentation for configuring SSL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) and it only mentions adding the `config.force_ssl = true` option, saying that will automatically engage the Rack::SSL middleware.

When I load the page, I'm seeing:

```
Index of /

    Name    Last modified   Size    Description

Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.8 Server at mysite.mydomain.com Port 443
```

The exact same thing happens if I remove the ssl config line in the rails app and use the Server tools to force the site to SSL (selecting a self-signed certificate for testing). What do I need to change to make it serve the `... myapp/current/public` folder, like it does when I have `config.force_ssl = false`?

Edit: A little more information. I see the following in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`:

```
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:49 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `My-Mac-mini.local' does NOT match server name!?
...
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using myserver.local for ServerName
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `My-Mac-mini.local' does NOT match server name!?
...
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Aug 26 10:57:50 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a config bug with Lion server. Finally fixed it in the file `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` by adding the line `NameVirtualHost *:443` after the line `NameVirtualHost *:80`. I assumed that the server would do that on its own accord if it were hosting several SSL sites, but it turns out that it doesn't.